# in_app_purchase: No purchase dialog is shown on iOS 13.4

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

The in app purchase flutter library isn’t working as it should on iOS 13.4

Once I click the buy button. The purchase dialog (the one where or asks for biometric confirmation) won’t show up.

I’ve tested on both Android and iOS 13.3.1 and it’s working flawlessly there.

By debugging the in_app_purchase code I was able to understand that the code it’s working well up until the following method in `FIAPaymentQueueHandler.m`

```
- (void)addPayment:(SKPayment *)payment {
  [self.queue addPayment:payment];
}
```

I’m not sure where it goes from there.